# automatically called functions while Object creation in python

Tags: python-3.x

What all inbuilt function call happen after creating a object from class? I know **init**() get called any other functions get called automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything occurs after `init()` unless you define it to, before `init()`;  however a call to the class' `__new__()` function will occur BEFORE the call to `init()`